# The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (124, 20) + inhomogeneous part

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 20 features in total to write into one matrix for my x. I had done the similar with 13 features out of the 20 features from previous steps, I didn't get any errors from those steps until I want to put all 20 features into my x matrix.

This is error pyCharm gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.2.5\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1500, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.2.5\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\Users\Crystal\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\FeaturesBuilding.py", line 159, in <module>
    x_vec1 = np.asarray(x_vec)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (124, 20) + inhomogeneous part.
```

This is the code contains error:

```
## Other features
    avg_chargetime_first5cycles = np.mean(battery_cycle['summary']['chargetime'][0:5])  # feature 14 - Avg chargetime (1-5)
    MaxTemp_cycles2_100 = battery_cycle['summary']['Tmax'][1:100]  # feature 15 - Maximum Temperature, cycles 2 to 100: [1:100]
    MinTemp_cycles2_100 = battery_cycle['summary']['Tmin'][1:100]  # feature 16 - Minimum Temperature, cycles 2 to 100: [1:100]
    Intg_T_t_cycles2_100 = np.trapz(battery_cycle['summary']['Tavg'][1:100])  # feature 17 - integral of temperature over time, cycles 2 to 100, the time means the cycle numbers
    intresis_2 = battery_cycle['summary']['IR'][1]  # feature 18 - Internal resistance at cycle 2
    MinIntResis_cycles2_100 = np.min(battery_cycle['summary']['IR'][1:100])  # feature 19 - minimum internal resistance cycles 2 to 100
    ir_100minus2 = battery_cycle['summary']['IR'][99] - battery_cycle['summary']['IR'][1]  # feature 20 - IR 100- IR 2
x_vec.append([logmin_deltaQ, logmean_deltaQ, logvar_deltaQ, logskew_deltaQ, logkurt_deltaQ, log2V_deltaQ, LR_slope_cycles2_100, LR_interc_cycles2_100, LR_slope_cycles91_100, LR_interc_cycles91_100, Qd_at_cycle2, maxQdminusQdatcycle2, Qd_at_cycle100, avg_chargetime_first5cycles, MaxTemp_cycles2_100, MinTemp_cycles2_100, Intg_T_t_cycles2_100, intresis_2, MinIntResis_cycles2_100, ir_100minus2]) # for feature_set3
    y_vec.append(bat_dict[tag]['cycle_life'])
    plt.plot(diffqd, V_lin_mod)
plt.xlabel('Qd_100-Qd_10')
plt.ylabel('Voltage V')
plt.show()

x_vec1 = np.asarray(x_vec)
y_vec1 = np.asarray(y_vec)[:,0,:]
# savedic = {'x_matrix':x_vec1,'y_vector':y_vec1}
# io.savemat('feature_set3.mat', savedic)
feature_number = 20
plt.scatter(x_vec1[:,feature_number-1],y_vec1)
plt.show()
```

I tried to print those 7 features to see if any of them contain non-number values, but all 7 of them are number. Based on my understanding, "inhomogeneous part" means when there are both values and strings show up in the same array, but in this case, my features only have numbers, I don't know how to fix this issue.
Please help. Thanks!!

Comment: No, the problem is with a mix of shapes.

Comment: Looks like some features are scalar (one value), others are 99 element arrays.  It might help if you showed what the working 13 feature case looks like.